# When I use RStudio to Generate PDF File，I Met this Error ：! Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: r-markdown

When I use RStudio to Generate PDF File，I Met this Error ：

```
 Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   (
l.349 \begin
            {minipage}[b]{\linewidth}\raggedright 

错误: LaTeX failed to compile bookdown.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See bookdown.log for more info.
停止执行
```

When I open the tex file：

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}\raggedright
独立性和可持续性
\end{minipage}
```

the Rmd file is

```
--- 
CJKmainfont: PingFangSC-Regular 
fontsize: "12pt" 
indent: true 
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{xeCJK} 
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: yes 
    latex_engine: xelatex 
    toc: yes 
    toc_depth: 1 
template: latex/template.tex 
documentclass: ctexbook 
link-citations: yes 
geometry: [b5paper, tmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=3.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm]  
colorlinks: yes 
---
```

latex/template.tex：

https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-chinese/blob/master/latex/template.tex

How can I fix it？ if I comment the code (#template:latex/template.tex) the Errors would be gone

Comment: Perhaps. you need to put a number before `\linewidth`, e.g. `1\linewidth`.

Comment: You need to show the minimal but entire Rmd file with YAML section. No one can reproduce the problem you faced, if you do not provide such an example.

Comment: @yucanghai You said the error is gone when you exclude `latex/template.tex`. Then, that `.tex` file should contain the source of error. You also have to show what is in there in your own question post, so that anyone can openly try and consider what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will successfully render the following Rmd to a pdf without any error.
Although @Stéphane Laurent commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74516659/when-i-use-rstudio-to-generate-pdf-file-i-met-this-error-missing-number-trea#comment131542316_74516659) that you may need to add a diameter to `\linewidth`, I do not think that is cause of the problem you faced, since the Rmd below using `\linewidth`, not `1\linewidth`, works fine.

The real problem may lay in other parts of your Rmd file, I suspect. However, you must post a reproducible example like the one I show in this answer, as I commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74516659/when-i-use-rstudio-to-generate-pdf-file-i-met-this-error-missing-number-trea#comment131587761_74516659), and present the contents of the `.log` file that is created when you knit your Rmd file.

```
---
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{ctex}
output:
  pdf_document: default
---

\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}\raggedright
独立性和可持续性
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

Comment: --- 
···
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
CJKmainfont: PingFangSC-Regular
fontsize: "12pt"
indent: true
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      header-includes:
        - \usepackage{xeCJK}
      in_header: latex/preamble.tex
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 1
template: latex/template.tex   
documentclass: ctexbook
link-citations: yes
geometry: [b5paper, tmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=3.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm]
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
colorlinks: yes
---

Comment: bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: latex/preamble.tex
    after_body: latex/after_body.tex
  keep_tex: yes
  #dev: "cairo_pdf"
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  template: latex/template.tex

actually if I comment the last code ： # template: latex/template.tex
this error is gone，so I can’t figure out what the problems

Comment: @yucanghai OK, thank you for your providing what you have done. Would you mind editing your own question post and adding the contents of your Rmd to the edit?

Comment: the file is ：
https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-chinese/blob/master/latex/template.tex

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the tables with unicode characters in Rmd caused this error. So, remove all the tables and knit. If this is the case, you may write tables in other ways, like using kableExtra.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: I had the overrun text inside one of table cells.

I had the same returned error message with Pandoc while converting Markdown file to PDF.

To solve, I had reduced the text, only to a few characters, only to display the table.
I added text to the point where it returns the error message.
Then, I added a new row for overrun text.